# Uploading Files in a specific directory on server

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin for the first time , and i'm working on a web application deployed in Tomcat 7 server . I want to upload files into a specific directory in the server and i want them to be stored there. 
So how to do it with Tomcat, Here's the code :

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    // Create the Upload component.
    Upload reportUpload = new Upload("Upload the report folder here",null);
        reportUpload.setButtonCaption("Upload The Report");


    Button reporGenearationbtn = new Button("Generate Report");
    reporGenearationbtn.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
        }
    });

    layout.addComponent(reportUpload);
    layout.addComponent(reporGenearationbtn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with tomcat,
it is handled by vaadin.

Look the the book of vaadin for a example.

https://vaadin.com/de/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.upload.html